# Получение объекта из stream или выброс исключения

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть код (здесь `Date date` условно, может быть любой POJO класс):

```java
Date date;
List<Date> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add(new Date());

Optional<Date> first = array.stream().filter(d -> d.after(new Date())).findFirst();

if (first.isPresent()) {
    date = first.get();
} else {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Могу я каким-то образом сделать это без `if/else`, чтобы сразу получить объект или бросить исключение, то есть дописать что-то после `findFirst()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не просто можно, но и нужно, Optional не принято использовать с условными операторами:

```
List<Date> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add(new Date());
Date result = array.stream().filter(d -> d.after(new Date())).findFirst().orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

P.S. лучше использовать класс LocalDateTime (либо другой класс из этого пакета в зависимости от потребоностей), т.к. класс Date по факту устарел.